# Has anyone reported looking for bandgap photoemission from III-V solar panels on spacecraft? Has any success ever been reported?

Tags: solar-power, visibility-of-spacecraft, space-surveillance, detection

I have asked a related question in Physics SE: [Do III-V based photovoltaics “glow” (photo-luminesce) when illuminated but not loaded?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/270125/83380) and the answer (as expected, as it must be) is yes.

**Question:** Have spacecraft ever been detected by direct bandgap photoemission from III-V solar panels? Has something like this ever been reported, or even *looked for* in some documented way?

The question [When there is more power than needed, are satellite photovoltaics shunted or open circuit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17516/12102) examines what happens to all of the energy deposited in photovoltaic cells by sunlight that has gone into the production of electron-hole pairs, which is roughly a third of the incident energy.

If you leave the PV cell disconnected, recombination will liberate that energy as heat, and the cells can get even hotter if not cooled properly. However, connect the PV cell to a shunt resistor and the heat will be deposited in the resistor which in many cases is more convenient and easier to cool.

*However* if the cells are made from high quality direct bandgap III-V material rather than silicon, a significant fraction of the recombination events can produce light at the bangap energy, which can be in the near IR or even visible for some materials.

Panels with III-V junctions, illuminated by Sunlight at 1 AU could be emitting of order 100 W/m^2 of light in a narrow band of wavelengths, something that would stand out like a sore thumb with the proper filter.

If they don't use shunting, you might even be able to tell if the spacecraft is loading their panels or leaving them open in times of low power usage.

Has this ever been reported or observed? Ever talked about?

Comment: Fascinating idea!  As far as you are aware does this include most satellites with modern (last 20 years) triple junction cells? What wavelength range is inferred?

Comment: @Puffin if a cell were a single III-V material (e.g. GaAs) this should be visible. In a double or triple junction system the short wavelength (high energy band gap) material in front should be mostly transparent to any light emitted from layers below so I think this can still happen. It's only direct band gap materials (I assume the III-V's)  that should make a lot of light, indirect band gaps (e.g. Si and Ge) will not make light. All that being said, I don't know what an actual triple junction cell looks like in terms of material stack.

Comment: @Puffin as far as wavelength, Planck's constant is about 1240 eV nm, so the wavelength would be 1240 nm divided by the band gap in eV. So just as an example pure GaAs would be around 850 nm (roughly) and [Indium gallium arsenide (In0.53Ga0.47As) is lattice matched to Indium Phosphide with a band gap of 0.74eV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-junction_solar_cell#Indium_phosphide_substrate) would be 1676 nm roughly, but III-V cells may have quantum wells so the wavelengths may be shorter than the intrinsic materials' band gaps.

Comment: I just saw [Dawn's glowing PV cells](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Black_light_test_of_Dawns_solar_cells.jpg) in Wikipedia's [Multi-junction solar cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-junction_solar_cell).

Comment: @Puffin [Do silicon solar cells act like an LED when you flip the voltage, or are we just seeing black body radiation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/527801/83380) and [video](https://youtu.be/6WGKz2sUa0w) linked therein. I've also just asked [Is infrared photoemission from silicon used in IC manufacturing diagnostics?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/478405/102305)