# Why does the PSLV first stage's exhaust plume turn to bluish at high altitude?

Tags: rockets, isro, exhaust, pslv, plume

After few seconds, post liftoff(anywhere between 60s and 90s), the exhaust plume of PSLV turns into a bluish colour. This is quite evident in night launches than day launches(obviously because the brilliance of sky overwhelms the exhaust plume intensity).

Drop in atomospheric pressure must play a role but what exactly causes this cause to happen?

Why does this happen? Is it common for all solid motors?

Picture for [reference](https://niteskypics.wordpress.com/2015/07/12/when-the-night-turned-day/) from PSLV C28 launch:
[image: enter link description here]

And a [video reference of PSLV C44 is here. Time mark 1:30](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HeyltNPvoi4&t=1m30s)

Comment: Exhaust from a solid rocket will certainly have plenty of left-over carbon atoms and molecules. C-H and C2 molecules [have strong blue (and green) emission lines](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/414244/102305) though I can't guess why there would be a change from the bright white incandescence at lower altitudes. Next time bring a piece of plastic transmission diffraction grating and hold it over part of your lens, and you can see if there are distinct emission lines.

Comment: This is blue engine exhaust, but it's different chemistry: [What is the cause of the blue light from LH2/LOX rocket engines?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16821/12102)

Comment: Any recommendations for the wavelengths I have to look for in the narrow-band pass filters? I think that will also do a neat job right?

Comment: Let me just do a bad guess. HTPB + Ammonium Perchlorate is the solid rocket fuel, which is supposed to burn with bright whitish/yellowish flame. Well could it be by any chance blue for the same reason why sky is blue?

Comment: @karthikeyan unless you have a super-fast filter wheel or a bunch of cameras each with a different filter, I think the filter is a bad idea. How can you know if you have a line? Use a blue filter, and everything will look blue. Get a grating. Even something like [this](https://www.rainbowsymphonystore.com/products/diffraction-grating-rolls) or [this](https://www.edmundoptics.com/f/Holographic-Diffraction-Grating-Film/11661/) (these are just examples) and experiment with flames or neon lights (if you can still find them) or various LEDs *before your next launch*.

Comment: The pitch should be pretty reliable so you can just use the grating equation to convert angle to wavelength conversion, and photograph a ruler to get pixel to angle conversion. You can also use a CD or DVD in reflection mode, but they are curved so it's much harder to do the calibration. [Here's something fancy](http://www.threehillsobservatory.co.uk/astro/spectroscopy_11.htm) from [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/73276/50110) and [here's something else](http://www.threehillsobservatory.co.uk/astro/spectra_20.htm).

Comment: Once you're done you can leave an answer [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21876/12102) ;-)

Comment: Any possibility that the exhaust gas condenses and scatters light from the flame itself? Because sunlight cannot be the cause as midnight launch has also created similar effect.