# How many of these six military "orbital threat" techniques have been demonstrated in a (more or less) publicly recognized way?

Tags: testing, spaceflight-firsts, military, weapon, qualification-testing

If you are having a good day then **under no circumstances should you read** the US Defense Intelligence Agency's [Challenges to Security in Space](https://www.dia.mil/Portals/27/Documents/News/Military%20Power%20Publications/Space_Threat_V14_020119_sm.pdf)<sup>1</sup> (Information cutoff date, January 2019) linked in Axios' [The rise of military space powers](https://www.axios.com/military-space-powers-770ad3ab-54ee-4387-adae-6e00bc69b099.html)

From page 10:

[image: Orbital Threats]

> Orbital Threats: Orbital or space-based systems are satellites that can deliver temporary or permanent effects against other spacecraft. These systems could include payloads such as **kinetic kill vehicles, radiofrequency jammers, lasers, chemical sprayers, high-power microwaves, and robotic mechanisms.** Some of these systems, such as robotic technology for satellite servicing and repair and debris removal, have peaceful uses but can also be used for military purposes.

**Question:** How many of these six military "orbital threat" techniques have been demonstrated in a (more or less) publicly recognized way? Here "more or less" means the owner of the technology does not have to acknowledge it, there just needs to be some publicly available fairly reputable source of information that this has taken place. The test could be under a "dual use" guise; for example a Chemical Sprayer weapon could be a robotic cubesat innocently spraying Windex® (or generic equivalent) rather than a fogging agent on a lens or window.

---

<sup>1</sup>and also don't read [Space Threat Assessment 2020](https://aerospace.csis.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Harrison_SpaceThreatAssessment20_WEB_FINAL-min.pdf)

Comment: companion question [Has a spacecraft ever actually sprayed a chemical (or anything) on to another spacecraft intentionally for any reason at all?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/52309/12102)

Comment: Not possibly related in any way: [Rocket Lab investigates rocket failure](https://www.axios.com/rocket-lab-rocket-failure-launch-investigation-df1072d4-de54-4812-abb0-681ed7d7b5f2.html)

Comment: You think??? That would be pretty wild.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens I asked [How vulnerable could space launch vehicles be to a “lone gunman”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18023/12102) September 2, 2016 and on October 2 (one month later): [So, um, SpaceX is looking for a sniper that shot the rocket, maybe from a nest at top of competitor's building..](https://twitter.com/swiftonsecurity/status/782371349620674560) Space is hard; things fail and/or blow up all the time.

Comment: Musk September 9, 2016: [Particularly trying to understand the quieter bang sound a few seconds before the fireball goes off. May come from rocket or something else.](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/774153847371501569)

Comment: I think laser and chemical are the only two that I haven't heard of.

Comment: One ephemeral threat I'm surprised I haven't seen is the old "you make a better door than a window" trick -- just positioning between a satellite and its target to deny access on a temporary basis.

Comment: Laser and mechanical ring bells for me. Mechanical because Northrop Grumman's MEV-1 and MEV-2 have demonstrated (and are still doing so) approaching, docking, and therefore taking control of, another satellite and then take it somewhere else. Publically this is extending the life of an otherwise 'dead' satellite (due to expended fuel). Laser rings a bell because of tests to optically blind satellites. I'm pretty sure both major agencies were testing that in orbit, i have a memory of reading about it, but I have no sources to link to. Ground based tests, for that purpose, tested definitely.

Comment: @blobbymcblobby I'm curious, why is "it's a military application dating from 1993" the reason that one "can't put (it as) an answer"? The quotes suggest you are quoting a source which is (presumably, hopefully) not secret.

Comment: not enough info, but was really interesting how obvious a weapon it was.

Comment: @blobbymcblobby where are you quoting from? I'm confused.

Comment: Chemical sprayers from orbit to destroy a hostile object in orbit, that would require a very precise rendezvous and a very precise application of the spray to achieve substantial damage with a small amount of the chemical. Even in a low orbit space is huge.

Comment: @Uwe without air, droplets would be just as ballistic as other projectiles so one can calculate and aim for an intersecting path. Sticking rather than bouncing is still a problem though.

Comment: Ballistic droplets may be fine, but finding a fluid that may be sprayed into a vacuum without too much evaporation as well as sticking rather than bouncing seems to be very difficult. The liquid should be able to build an opaque layer on an image sensor that would exist at last some hours, days, weeks.

Comment: @Uwe there are plenty of oils that can have low rates of evaporation in space (some familiar extremes are fomblin oil and vacuum greases e.g. Apiazon-L). If modern spy satellite telescopes are anything like the older Hubble-like ones, they're open tubes with a mirror in the back. Ballistic blobs of heavy oil bouncing around inside will get on the mirror(s) and then you don't have spy-grade imagery any more. These can stay for quite a long time.

Comment: @Uwe There's also liquid metals (mercury, sodium, or eutectics) and my favorite: [ionic liquids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_liquid) proposed for rotating liquid telescope mirrors https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/41027/7982 Wow this is getting fun... now I want to design a [Mimetic polyalloy hunter-killer liquid metal space robot!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-1000) :-)

Comment: @Tristan Orbital intercept is difficult enough that if you're going to go to the trouble of getting there, something more permanent than a photobomb is A) easily accomplished, and B) more effective.

Answer (score 2):

robotic mechanisms

Further to NG's MEV-1 and MEV-2 projects already mentioned, China joined this club in 2021-22.

Although termed "space debris mitigation" by the PRC, its uses otherwise, just like for MEV-1 and -2, are obvious.

https://spacenews.com/chinas-shijian-21-spacecraft-docked-with-and-towed-a-dead-satellite/

[image]

> China’s Shijian-21 towed dead satellite to a high graveyard orbit

> China’s Shijian-21 space debris mitigation satellite has docked with a defunct Chinese satellite to drastically alter its geostationary orbit, demonstrating capabilities only previously exhibited by the United States.

> In late December (2021), Shijian-21 approached the defunct Beidou-2 G2 navigation satellite, matching its orbit and rendezvousing with, and eventually docking with the spacecraft
>
> Shijian-21 performed a large burn Jan.22, taking the Beidou-2 G2 satellite 3,000 kilometers above the GEO belt.
>
> The docking and subsequent engine burn — which was unusually large, taking it beyond the usual “graveyard” orbit of 300 kilometers above GEO
>
> “You could look at China working to develop the capability to remove inactive satellites on orbit as a way in which it is being a responsible space actor and cleaning up debris that it caused. Or you could use the lens that a lot of the US-based China watchers use and say that this could indicate that China is developing an on-orbit offensive capability.”

> USA 270, Chinese Shiyan-12 encounter
>
> “What we’re showing here is counterspace technology. So, they’re kind of employing a tactic, technique [and] procedure, or TTP, as it’s known by the U.S. Department of Defense, and are showing that they’ve got the exquisite, timely and responsive SSA to understand events that are unfolding.”
>
> The closest approach between the U.S. and one of the Chinese satellites was around 73 kilometers, according to COMSPOC. Not close enough to threaten a potential collision, but enough for one party to decide if it wanted to leave the vicinity to avoid potential intelligence gathering or other activities by the other.

Similarly:

In 2021 Astroscale did a tech demo in space of a magnetic capture and release using a CubeSat as a target.

[image]

> Astroscale
>
> We are excited to announce that ... our #ELSAd spacecraft successfully demonstrated repeated magnetic captures in orbit today!

> The ELSA-d spacecraft of Japan-based startup Astroscale has successfully captured a simulated piece of space junk, completing the first phase of a demonstration mission that could pave the way for a less cluttered future in orbit.

https://www.space.com/astroscale-first-space-junk-capture-demonstration

Other methods, from the Soviet era:

https://www.thespacereview.com/article/3536/1

> Other satellite defense techniques studied by TashKBM were electronic countermeasures, measures to reduce the radar cross-section of satellites, the deployment of decoys, the use of aerosol particles to obscure satellites from attacking vehicles and what are described as “heat screens.”

[image]

> Few details have been revealed about the Nauka experiments related to satellite defense. Androsov mentions tests of “space-to-space projectiles,” “transformable and inflatable structures,” as well as radar-absorbing materials.

> plasma stealth technology.
>
> Just like the plasma that naturally builds around a spacecraft during re-entry can cause communication blackouts, artificially created plasma clouds can theoretically absorb radar waves aimed at satellites in orbit. The principle was tested using so-called magneto plasma dynamic (MPD) engines, which expel plasma at very high speeds

> Soviet-era publications had already described one such plasma engine having flown on Cosmos-728 in April 1975 and later publications identified another one carried by Cosmos-780 in November/December 1975.
>
> Mounted on the forward end of the Nauka modules, the 2.5-kilowatt MPD engines were fueled by potassium and used for experiments called Kren (“roll”), at least one purpose of which was to test the stealthy effect of plasma clouds.

> Testing plasma stealth technology on Soyuz
>
> A similar test of plasma stealth technology was conducted in 1976 on an uncrewed Soyuz spacecraft
>
> Fed by lithium, the 17-kilowattengine was successfully ignited on December 13, ejecting ions at a speed of up to 60 kilometers per second. According to Androsov, the resulting plasma cloud made the vehicle temporarily disappear from radar screens, but the 2012 article says it also had the unwanted effect that the command to shut down the engine did not immediately reach the vehicle, leaving little propellant and battery power for a second burn that turned out to be far less effective.

> Istrebitel Sputnikov
>
> explosive charges were mounted on short booms extending from either side of the interceptor satellite. The Soviet Union launched about 20 interceptors under the IS program between 1968 and 1982, with several of them successfully destroying specially launched target satellites.

[image]

14K168 Burevestnik (2011)

> is an umbrella name for an ASAT program that includes both space-based and non-space-based elements
>
> a space-based system that itself seems to have two components (Burevestnik-M and Burevestnik-KA-M)

Also:

https://www.russianspaceweb.com/spacecraft_military.html

Answer (score -1):

The obvious answer: Kinetic Kill(ASAT). China, the US (and others) have demonstrated their capabilities to do this in real (the DIA report mentioned in the question discussed this). Although in these so-called "experiments", the exercise was to destroy one's own satellite  with a missile (not sat-vs-sat as implied by the extracted illustration), the distinction between a missile, a rocket or a satellite used as a weapon is tenuous, the main difficulty being to predict exactly the trajectory of the target (assuming it does not have maneuverability). Beside the madness of such a move (a clear declaration of war), the environmental impact would be deleterious to mankind (the so-called "Kessler syndrome" popularized by the movie Gravity).

So, in most eventuality, to neutralize an opponent's space asset, w/o raising suspicion and worldwide condemnation, some more discrete techniques are needed. Spraying chemicals is rather a joke, unless you know how to navigate (quickly?) your little spraying can close to you opponent's asset w/o raising suspicion. A better idea, if time and patience is on your side, is to neutralize an orbit, or an altitude range: just maneuver your little satellite(s) to the orbit(s) you want to neutralize, then pretend to inadvertently 'lose' some parts there and let the Kessler syndrome do its work. I would call this "dropping nails on a highway". It won't work well for higher orbits.

Anyway, this question  leads me to advocate for some form of binding international law quickly to protect our Near-Earth space before it is too late. Today the space-capable nations are playing with fire and it is jungle's law.

Comment: Were those kinetic kills from satellites, as the question asks, or by earth based [missiles](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2007/jan/19/china.spaceexploration1) ([China 2007](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2007_Chinese_anti-satellite_missile_test))?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! In addition to that, "Just Google the term 'ASAT test'" is not a proper Stack Exchange answer. You need to google yourself and cite and quote the sources you've found. You can have a look around at other answers in the site to see how this is standard, or even see the amount of work I put in to supporting the question with sources.

Comment: and don't forget India! [India just shot down a satellite from the ground. At what altitude range is the resulting debris field?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35093/12102) and [How does the US's 2008 debris cloud compare to India's 2019 and China's 2007 contributions?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35248/12102)

Comment: @Fred, everything man-made that goes to space is "from the ground". So, the distinction between a missile and a satellite is hard to understand for me. The initial question, to my understanding is just a threat to a space asset.

Comment: @NgPh the question asks about threats from orbit; *orbital threats*. "Orbital or space-based systems are satellites that can..."

Comment: @uhoh. Forgive my inexperience. Anyway, my real point is that the Web literature on "kinetic kill" is large. Consequently, the answer should be obvious: kinetic kill is THE threat, none of the other 5 techniques in the quoted illustration come close to that one. On the debate of whether the US "experiment" polluted less than the Chinese (or the Indian), I find that question irrelevant. Either you are a responsible user of the commons, or you are not. The same goes for industrial practices, fishing, ... especially when you are a permanent member of the UN Sec. Council.

Comment: @uhoh, Thanks for the clarification (I missed this extract from the report - I thought the illustration misleading). It is then mind boggling that there are thinktanks who are paid to write such scenarios (and divulge it on the Web!).

Comment: @NgPh: True, all human made things in space are launched from earth but the difference between a satellite kill & an earth based missile kill is a satellite is launched & orbits the earth for a period, maybe years, before it receives a signal from earth to attack another satellite. A targeted missile kill from earth is a missile that is launched just prior to the destruction of the targeted satellite.

Comment: @Fred, I realized my mistake (cf my reply @uhoh). So, what is being discussed is the concept of pre-positioning weapons in space, in a disguised way to workaround the Outer Space Treaty (1967) - kind of. This being said, I doubt any benefit of such "space-based attack". Space is a harsh environment for electronics. Concerning the element of surprise, which is the basis of any military dogma, approaching a target flying at 7-8 Km/s w/o being noticed will be challenging. And this assumes that your target does not have any maneuvering capability...

Comment: @NgPh a gentle and reversible `-1` vote as a reminder that because Stack Exchange is open to the entire internet, there are certain conventions and rules we must stick to. Answer posts must attempt to answer the question *as asked*, and comments should work towards resolving issues about the *suitability and clarity of the posts* rather than serve as a discussion forum. Comment chains that end up as discussions will eventually be moved to chat rooms or simply deleted without warning. If you can't adjust your answer post to address the question *as asked/written* it may simply be deleted.