# Has a spacecraft ever actually sprayed a chemical (or anything) on to another spacecraft intentionally for any reason at all?

Tags: record, chemistry, military, weapon

The question [How many of these six military "orbital threat" techniques have been demonstrated in a (more or less) publicly recognized way?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/52308/12102) begins:

> If you are having a good day then **under no circumstances should you read** the US Defense Intelligence Agency's [Challenges to Security in Space](https://www.dia.mil/Portals/27/Documents/News/Military%20Power%20Publications/Space_Threat_V14_020119_sm.pdf)<sup>1</sup> (Information cutoff date, January 2019) linked in Axios' [The rise of military space powers](https://www.axios.com/military-space-powers-770ad3ab-54ee-4387-adae-6e00bc69b099.html)

and one of the six is "Chemical Sprayers".

**Question:** I'm just curious, has a spacecraft ever actually sprayed a chemical (or anything) on to another spacecraft *intentionally* for any reason at all? If so, what was sprayed, and why?

---

From page 10:

[image: Orbital Threats]

> Orbital Threats: Orbital or space-based systems are satellites that can deliver temporary or permanent effects against other spacecraft. These systems could include payloads such as **kinetic kill vehicles, radiofrequency jammers, lasers, chemical sprayers, high-power microwaves, and robotic mechanisms.** Some of these systems, such as robotic technology for satellite servicing and repair and debris removal, have peaceful uses but can also be used for military purposes.

---

<sup>1</sup>and also don't read [Space Threat Assessment 2020](https://aerospace.csis.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Harrison_SpaceThreatAssessment20_WEB_FINAL-min.pdf)

Comment: companion question [How many of these six military “orbital threat” techniques have been demonstrated in a (more or less) publicly recognized way?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/52308/12102)

Comment: Innocent-me only can imagine nitrogen (or air) being sprayed onto an astronomical device to clean a mirror from dust.

Comment: @B--rian I'm going to start a company and launch a fleet of ion-propelled cubesats that go around spraying and cleaning lenses and windows of spacecraft cameras and optical sensors. *I'm going to be rich!* I'm going to become a billionaire and start a space tourism company and wear a blue jumpsuit and make my own astronaut wings and everything!

Comment: @blobbymcblobby it looks like you are quoting a source which is (presumably, hopefully) not secret. Consider posting as an answer [unless it's a secret](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/52308/how-many-of-these-six-military-orbital-threat-techniques-have-been-demonstrate?noredirect=1#comment191284_52308)!

Comment: ah, no demonstrable information to say it happened or was tested, especially given the age. Given I've noticed NASA and other such papers on Chinese websites I rather think that they've looked at these too..

Comment: @blobbymcblobby I don't understand what you are saying but okay

Answer (score 4):

Clickbait header:

**The Russians sprayed chemicals from Mir onto the Space Shuttle!!**

However, it was all coordinated up front.

Jet exhaust from the Mir space station thrusters were deliberately impinged on a plate mounted on the shuttle's robot arm.

> DTO
> 829 - Plume Impingement
> and Contamination
>
> The primary objective
> of this
> was to record data on a plate mounted on the RMS during the firing of the Mir
> 13-kg thrusters.
> Additional
> data were collected
> during primary RCS thruster firings
> after a cold-soak
> to aid in expanding
> the data base. These data have been
> given to the sponsor
> and an evaluation
> of the data will be reported in separate documentation.

[image]

> Data gained from this experiment was critical in the development of the bipropellant plume contamination model for the Russian 130 N engine, which is used extensively on the Russian segment of the ISS, as well as all the Progress and Soyuz vehicles.

Sources:

- [STS-74 Post Flight Report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19970001479/downloads/19970001479.pdf)
- [Thrust Plume Induced Contamination Measurements from the PIC and SPIFEX Flight Experiments](https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/full/2003ESASP.540..225S)

Acronymology:

- DTO - Developmental Test Objective
- RCS - Reaction Control System
- RMS - Remote Manipulator System (robot arm)