# What happens if a centimeter-sized particle hits a spaceship at orbital velocity?

Tags: spacecraft, impact, meteoroid

How much damage would a centimeter sized particle weighing a few grams do when it impacts a spaceship at orbital velocity? Let's say 30 km/s (Earth's rotation speed around the Sun). Such a particle certainly has enough kinetic energy to destroy any near future conceivable spacecraft, but will all that energy be converted into an explosion? Or will such a particle mostly just punch through the ship as a cloud of plasma so that only a limited amount of its kinetic energy is converted to ship damage?

Comment: different question but related: [Why would a box full of 1cm balls released into LEO be so scary to an engineer supporting the ISS?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21891/12102)

Comment: At 30km/s, 1g of material has 100g of TNT worth of kinetic energy. 1cm^3 will be between 1 and 8 grams depending on material; 1g ice, 2g rock, 7g iron. The damage will act similarly to a shaped charge along the impact trajectory.

Comment: That 1 g of material provides enough energy to heat, melt and vaporize about 50 grams of iron if my calculations are correct.